# Mixing database results from 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, twitter, eloquent

I am trying to implement the feed feature in twitter, that is, I have a query that is returning results from a `tbl_a` but I also have a table `tbl_b` that contains info of users that I want to promote. Just like twitter does it that in addition to normal tweets from friends we periodically see promoted ads. I really dont know how to implement this feature in laravel any help would be appreciated. The query returning results from `tbl_a` is below

```
$services  = Service::postOnly()
            ->whereIn('category_id', Auth::user()
            ->userCats()
            ->pluck('id'))
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

this is the query i would like to combine with another query from tbl_b, the table that contains the promoted ads.

Comment: You have to add relation between these two tables, you can also use join

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using JOIN statement?

```
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
```

Comment: please explain why there has to be a relationship between the 2 tables